# Eclipse package explorer tied to editor window

Tags: eclipse, package-explorer

In Eclipse (latest version) I ended up with the situation seen below. I accidentally rested a book on my keyboard and through some magical key sequence managed to have a package explorer bar locked into the top of my editor window.

I've spent a while searching on google and playing around in eclipse to try and remove this with no success (the bar seems locked in place and right clicking does nothing..).  Any ideas on how to remove it (its really annoying me)?  Thanks.

Oh, and this only happens in the Java perspective (which is the perspective I was using when I accidentally triggered this).

[alt text http://etanshaul.com/demonstration.gif](http://etanshaul.com/demonstration.gif)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called Breadcrumb. 
[See here about it](http://www.vasanth.in/2008/08/18/eclipse-tip-java-editor-breadcrumb-navigation-bar/).

Your package explorer is a separate thing, which you can show from `Window > Show view > Package explorer`.

If you don't like the breadcrumb, [see this](http://loadcontext.blogspot.com/2008/08/eclipse-34-breadcrumbs-hide-and-show.html) for tips of hiding it.